# Como faço uma struct com ponteiro para uma função que imprime a própria struct em C

Tags: c, funções, ponteiro

Tenho uma estrutura:

```
struct conteudo{
    tipo valor;  //valor qualquer
    void (func*)(void*); //ponteiro para função que imprime a propria estrutura
};
```

Gostaria de saber como faço para chamar essa função para a própria célula, já que `conteudo->func(conteudo);` não funciona.

Answer (score 1):

A linguagem C não é orientado a objetos, então ela não possui um ponteiro como o `this` para uma método conseguir acessar os membros de uma struct.

A forma que encontrei para fazer isso é o seguinte, você cria uma struct com um ponteiro para uma função print, declara uma função print fora da struct, no main quando criar a struct você atribui o seus valores e função print ao ponteiro da struct, e na hora de chamar o ponteiro da struct precisa atribuir no parametro a struct que precisa ser escrita, isso é redundante, mas é o mais proximo que consigo fazer com C o que eu faria com uma linguagem OO.

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct Conteudo {
  int valor;

  void (*print)(struct Conteudo* conteudo);
};

void print(struct Conteudo* conteudo) {
  printf("Valor: %d\n", conteudo->valor);
}

int main() {
  struct Conteudo conteudo;

  conteudo.valor = 10;

  conteudo.print = print;

  conteudo.print(&conteudo);

  return 0;
}
```